# ros2 remapping wildcard

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, remapping, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to remap a set of topic using the '**' wildcard as explain in http://design.ros2.org/articles/static_remapping.html#replacement-part-of-a-rule

I got the error :

```
rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.RCLError: failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse remap rule: '-r /fmu/in/**:=/px4_1/\1'. Error: Wildcard '**' is not implemented, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:1167, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:371
```

Have I written the rule wrong or does this wildcard really not implemented ?

Note: I got the same behaviour with '*'.

extract from my yaml file

```
  - node:
      remap:
        -
          from: '/fmu/*'
          to: '/px4_$(var i)/fmu/\\1'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416910/ros2-remapping-wildcard/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to give you the answer you don't want to hear:

It is not implemented yet. See these issues:

https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/232
https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/233
https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/234

At least now you know...

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) with karma: 145 on 2023-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1